# jdk. Задача перевести число в двоичный код и вывести в выбранном примитивном типе данных

Tags: java, binary

Переводить через binary() нельзя).
Перевести число в двоичный код я смог, но не понимаю как вывести
в определённом типе данных.

**пример вывода:**

```
 121 = 
    byte:    "01111001"
    short:    "00000000 01111001"
    int:    "00000000 00000000 00000000 01111001"
    long:    "00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01111001"
    float:    "0 10000101 11100100000000000000000"
    double: "0 10000000101 1110010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

Comment: А язык то какой? javascript в тегах наверное лишний..

Comment: java development kit

Comment: @mxrph, и что именно у вас не получилось? где код который вы пытались реализовать?